# Rails DESTROY action on nested resource without ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, resources

I have the following resource set up in my `routes.rb` file:

```
namespace :api, path: '/', defaults: { format: 'json' }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :yums do
      resources :likes,  only: [:create, :destroy, :index] do
        match '/', to: 'likes#destroy', via: 'delete'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I also wrote a spec to test my requests:

```
describe "Like API requests" do
  before (:each) do 
    host! 'api.example.com'

    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @other_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @yum = FactoryGirl.create(:yum, user: @other_user)
  end

  describe "liking a Yum" do
    it "should increase the Yum's Like count" do
      expect do
        post "/v1/yums/#{@yum.id}/likes", { authorization: token_header(@user.auth_token) }
      end.to change(@yum.reload.likes, :count).by(1)
    end
  end

  describe "unliking a Yum" do
    it "should increase the Yum's Like count" do
      expect do
        delete "/v1/yums/#{@yum.id}/likes", { authorization: token_header(@user.auth_token) }
      end.to change(@yum.reload.likes, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end
end
```

I want the `Likes` controller to not require an ID for the destroy action since I use methods on my user model to like and unlike, but this scheme doesn't seem to be working, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a route in your routes.rb like :

```
match "v1/yums/:yum_id/likes", to: "likes#destroy", via: "delete", defaults: { id: nil }
```